# ASP dynamic DropDownList selected index

Tags: c#, asp.net

My web form starts out as two TextBoxes, two Buttons, a CheckBoxList (bound to the results of a database query), and an empty DropDownList.

When the user enters a search phrase into the first TextBox and hits enter (or clicks the first Button, "Search"), a GridView appears, populated with rows pulled from the database. When the user hits the Select button on one of the rows, the DropDownList is populated (bound to results of a database query) and enabled (if the query returned results -- if there were no results, it remains disabled). When the second Button ("Save Settings") is clicked, the relevant data is saved to the DB, the GridView's selection is cleared, and the DropDownList is cleared and disabled.

All of the above works. The problem comes from the DropDownList. I can't get the C# code to recognize the changing SelectedIndex; depending on how I shuffle my code around, the index is always either 0 (and the DropDownList is forced to stay on the first item), or -1 (and the list becomes disabled).

DropDownList code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="myList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    DataTextField="MyName" DataValueField="MyID" 
    Enabled="False" onselectedindexchanged="myList_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

C# code:

```
protected void myGrid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        if (myGrid.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            int id = int.Parse(myGrid.Rows[myGrid.SelectedIndex].Cells[2].Text);
            connection.Open();

            string query = "..."; // Omitted for brevity; the query is correct
            SqlDataSource source = new SqlDataSource(connectionString, query);
            source.SelectParameters.Add("Param1", TypeCode.String, id.ToString());
            DataTable dt = ((DataView)source.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)).Table;
            dt.AcceptChanges();
            myList.DataSource = dt;
            myList.DataBind();
            myList.Enabled = myList.Items.Count != 0;

            if (!myList.Enabled)
            {
                myList.Items.Add(new ListItem("No Results", "0"));
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void myList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedIndex == -1
}
```

I've read that there are some problems with DropDownList while searching for a solution to my problem, but besides the note to set AutoPostBack="True", none of the other situations I've found have helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common reason on why the DropDownList loses its SelectedIndex value is, that during the postback is binded again with data. Do you populate data to the DropDownList somewhere else in your code? Maybe there is something else that causes the SelectedIndex event of the GridView to fire again?

Another thought is that changing the Enabled status of the DropDownList might cause this behavior. Try your code without disabling the DropDownList, and see if something changes.

Comment: Well, don't I feel silly. `myList.Items.Clear()` was in `Page_Load`. That'd certainly do it!